# How to determine which edge of control user is leaving UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

What I am trying to achieve is to determine if the user dragged a tile off the left edge or the right edge of a control and if more pages exist navigate to other page.  I have tried the control leave event but it does not seem to send which side the user left(unless i missed something which is entirely possible).  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no such event or provided way, but you shold be able to detect it by getting a `Point` using the `GetCurrentPoint()` method and then using logic to determine which side it is, right?

Comment: It is harder that way which appears to be what i will have to do I initially came from winforms that was easier to determine

Comment: Can use point leave?